# Eclipse Voice browser/server plugin

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, vxml

I am trying to find a way to run VoiceXML applications from inside Eclipse.

From what i understand i need 3 components.

1. A platform to write servlets/voicexml. That's Eclipse Indigo (3.7.1) bundled with [WebSphere Voice Toolkit V6.2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/voicetoolkit.html) plugin.
2. A web server. That's Apache Tomcat.
3. A voice server/voiceXML browser. I haven't managed to find something that works with the current setup.

I have already setup the first 2 components.
Created a servlet and deployed a vxml file in Tomcat.
There is a way to simulate the dialog from the WebSphere Voice Toolkit V6.2 itself. 
But now i want to call/run my vxml application from inside eclipse using a voice server and interacting through microphone-voice input.

I tried a couple of tools (Voxeo's Prophecy, VoiceObjects for Eclipse) but i haven't managed to find a way and synthesize those tools to work together with eclipse.

Could someone direct me to the right way in order to run vxml files locally and interacting with voice (perhaps through an eclipse plugin)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal to debug the servlet code or the VoiceXML logic? If just the servlet code, and you can expose your application server to the application, you should be able to do this with most platforms.

If you are looking for an all-in-one VoiceXML environment, I'm not aware of any that exist/generally available.  The closest solution would be JVoiceXML.  It is a Java based VoiceXML platform that has fairly good specification coverage.  It's main purpose isn't to be a test tool, so I would expect you to have to manipulate it somewhat.

I would consider this framework the best open source VoiceXML I've come across.  I am working on using it as a test tool within my environment and have pushed back some of my changes into the project.  In particular, an SRGS/SISR implementation and a variety of smaller fixes.  The changes I haven't pushed mostly involve breaking changes to the client interface so my test cases can have more control/insight into the VoiceXML engine.

Comment: My goal was to find just a voicexml browser so i could test/interact using my voice (with) the dialog system i had built in IBM's WebSphere Voice Toolkit V6.2 Eclipse plugin i.e. run through the dialog utterances like it was a live application (A: says this. B: replies back etc.). This was just a semester project i had a couple of months ago. I learned about JVoiceXML back then, but i followed the safest approach. So i ported my voicexml app to an earlier version of IBM's WebSphere Toolkit (V3.1) that was accompanied with a voice server too. Anyway, thanks for your time to reply back Jim.